# Dynamic class variable for Marshmallow Schema?

Tags: python, python-3.x, marshmallow

I'm making several Schemas using Marshmallow. Some of them would be `UserSchema`, `PatientSchema` and `AppointmentSchema`. I'm also making a "overall" `FeedbackSchema`, looking like this:

```
class FeedbackSchema(Schema):
    success = fields.Bool()
    message = fields.String()
    error = fields.String()
    data = ?
```

I imagine that when a end user asks for the route `/users/all` it will result in a `FeedbackSchema` where the `data` field is filled with a list of all users. That is, `fields.List(fields.Nested(UserSchema))`. However if they go to `/patient/1` the `data` field is filled with a single patient, that is `fields.Nested(PatientSchema)`.

What I want is to not have to create several different `FeedbackSchema`s being virtually identical, except in their definition of the type of the `data` class variable.

How can I achieve this dynamically? Some sort of class factory I'm not aware of?

My current solution is using this subclassing:

```
class UserFeedbackSchema(FeedbackSchema):
    data = fields.Nested(UserSchema)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using inheritance?

Comment: @PoP I've edited in my current solution, which does use inheritance. I guess my problem is that I still require quite a few of those classes, and like this I'll end up with a bunch of different names for them. Am I missing something simple? I'm just defining the `data` field differently in each one.